# Java random MediaPlayer playlist

Tags: java, android, eclipse, media-player

I'm creating an android app on eclipse. When I start my activity I've made it play music (song1.wav)in the background. However how could I change it so that it plays a list of songs in a random order?

Here's my code:

```
public class BCTR extends Activity {
     protected MediaPlayer song1MediaPlayer;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bctr);

        Button homebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homebtn);



          final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volbar);
            volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
            volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
            volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
                }
            });


            song1MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(BCTR.this, R.raw.song1);
            song1MediaPlayer.start();

            homebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View v)
              {

                   song1MediaPlayer.stop();
                  Intent intent = new Intent(BCTR.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
              }
            });



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

So basically I'd have song1 - song10 in my raw folder and I'd want them all to play when the activity starts but in a random order.

Comment: Question: Can a song be played more times, or do you want to play them all exactly once?

Comment: all exactly once @LajosArpad

Comment: Answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have an `AbstractList<Integer>` variable called `indexes`, having 0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1 inside them as their values. Now, let's have a method responsible for randomly getting the index of and index element from the `indexes` variable:

```
public int getRandomNumber(numberOfElements) {
    java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random();
    return rnd.nextInt(numberOfElements);
}
```

You need to build your `AbstractList<Integer>` containing the `indexes` (for instance you can use the `ArrayList` class for instantiation) and then

```
while (indexes.size() > 0) {
   int winnerIndex = indexes.remove(getRandomNumber(indexes.size())).intValue();
   //code, which displays the music
}
```

Comment: so under the part where you've got the music code. I'd just put song1MediaPlayer.start(); song2MediaPlayer.start(); song3MediaPlayer.start(); and so on?

Comment: You should put those commands into an array, then create the indexes set which will be used for randomizing and delete already played song indexes in the process.